# Why don't items get selected 'internally' when I select them 'visually' in Windows Form Application ListBox?

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, listbox, selecteditem, listboxitem

I'm trying to check whether an item is selected in a `ListBox` or not but with no luck. When I select an item 'visually' it doesn't get selected 'internally'. What I mean by that is when I select an item, it turns blue so I assume it is now selected but turns out I'm wrong, it's not. Why's that? I tried various methods but none of them worked. It's just mind boggling for me. Any and all help would be appreciated.

Here's what I tried:

```
this->listBoxFoobar->Items->Add(String::Format("Foobar1", 1));
this->listBoxFoobar->Items->Add(String::Format("Foobar2", 2));
this->listBoxFoobar->Items->Add(String::Format("Foobar3", 3));
this->listBoxFoobar->TopIndex = 0;
this->listBoxFoobar->SetSelected(0, true);

// Check whether one of the three items is selected
private: System::Void buttonFoobar_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    this->listBoxFoobar->TopIndex = 0;
    if (!this->listBoxFoobar->GetSelected(0) || !this->listBoxFoobar->GetSelected(1) || !this->listBoxFoobar->GetSelected(2)) {
        MessageBox::Show("Something went wrong?", "Pity", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your function doesn't do what the comment above it suggests it's supposed to do. The expression `(!this->listBoxFoobar->GetSelected(0) || !this->listBoxFoobar->GetSelected(1) || !this->listBoxFoobar->GetSelected(2))` can only be false if all three items are selected at the same time.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik "if all three items are selected at the same time" - isn't that the purpose of `&&` (and) and not `||` (or)?

Comment: Isn't what the purpose of them? Your condition says: "if item 0 is not selected, OR item 1 is not selected, OR item 2 is not selected, then complain". Therefore, you complain as soon as at least one is *not* selected; and conversely, you don't complain only when all three *are* in fact selected. See also: [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks, I finally realised what's the problem here.